If $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = x^4$, prove that $f \circ g = g \circ f$.

If $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = x^4$, prove that $f \circ g = g \circ f$. ($x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$)

The solution is simple:
$$
D(g \circ f) = Im(f(x)) = \mathbb{R} \text{ and } (g \circ f)(x) = x^{12} \therefore Im(g \circ f) = \mathbb{R}_+
$$
$$
D(f \circ g) = Im(g(x)) = \mathbb{R_+} \text{ and } (f \circ g)(x) = x^{12} \therefore Im(g \circ f) = \mathbb{R}_+
$$
Well, they have both the same image but different domains.
The question is: Are functions with different domains really different from each other?

Are you sure about the different domains? When you write $D(f\circ g)$, you are looking at $f\circ g$, not at $f$ on the image of $g$

@Thomas basically, that's what i am thinking (and bringing me confusion): $x$ is substituted by $g(x)$, therefore the domain of $f \circ g(x)$ is now the image of $g(x)$...

yes, but what $f\circ g$ is applied to is $x$ in the first place, so the domain of $f\circ g$ is the same as the domain of $g$. You just have to make sure that the image of $g$ is a subset of the domain of $f$ to ensure the composition is well defined. Since this condition does not lead to any need for a restriction, the domain of the composition can be taken as the domain of the inner function.

The domain of $f\circ g$ equals the domain of $g,$ while the domain of $g\circ f$ equals the domain of $f.$
Since the domain of $f$ and the domain of $g$ are both $\mathbb R,$ both compositions have the same domain.

isn't the domain of $a \circ b$ the image of $b$?

No, it's not. You probably need to re-read whatever information you have about the domain of functions, but in general, $D(f \circ g) = D(g)$. For $f \circ g$ to even be defined requires that $Im(g) \subset D(f)$, but that does nothing to alter the domain.

thanks haha
it must be a typo on the material i am using

@Graphiel. If $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ then, writing $X \overset{f}{\rightarrow} Y \overset{g}{\rightarrow}Z,$ one can see that $g\circ f: X\to Z.$

Maybe I don't understand.  You claim that the domain of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ equals $\mathbb R$?  Isn't the domain of $f\circ g$ the preimage of the image of the domain of $g$ under $f$, that is $f^{-1}(g(Dg))$?

@MichaelHoppe. Note that I wrote "$f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$". With your example there is no set $Y$ such that $f:\mathbb R\to Y$ and $g:Y\to \bullet.$ We have to confine the domain of $f$ to a subset of $[-1,1].$

$D(g(f(x)) = \mathbf{R} = D(f(g(x))$
So, they are the same functions.
